# Open Folder , Select the file using C# / WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to know what is the best way to explore windows folder , select one then save it your project .
I am building an application to edit text , I would like to save it in a folder , save it in specific format .

**Update:**

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
```

After opening the folder , I would like to select it and get the directory .

Comment: What have you tried? This question is unclear and on top of that it doesn't appear that you've made any attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) and [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx).

[StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) and [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) are pretty useful, too!

[EDIT:] Take a look at [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) to select folders.

This code should return you the path of a folder:

```
        public string GetFolderPath()
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog Dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            while (Dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Dialog.Reset();
            }
            return Dialog.SelectedPath;
        }
```

Comment: I would like to select a folder , not a file ! Can any one of these help !

Answer (score 1):

You have several options, unfortunately I'm not entirely sure what you've tried.  You can accomplish this in a very basic way such as:

```
using(FolderBrowserDialog fd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
     DialogResult result = fd.ShowDialog();
     if(result == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(fd.SelectedPath.ToString());
     }
}
```

The above code will actually load the `FolderBrowserDialog` once a selection is made it will post it into a `MessageBox`.  Obviously you can point or map it anywhere you'd like, this is a very basic example.

Comment: I would like to select the folder and get the directory of this folder ! Plz , Check the last Update of the post

Comment: @ImnotaGeek There you go.

Comment: I am follwoing this post http://rpelepei.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-open-file-dialog-window-in-wpf.html

Comment: @ImnotaGeek That isn't your question though-

Comment: I have problem with "DialogResult.OK)"

Comment: @ImnotaGeek Your using WPF you have to physically reference the `WindowsForms`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using visual c# you could use the built in file browser to do such activity. However, there is no code posted so I'm not sure what you have tried.